# In R. Split a variable into three eual length and mean and median of corresponding another variable by the length

Tags: r, split

I have a dataset including "depth", "value" and "year" as below. Number of value in each year is not the same and depth of a year is continuous.

```
    depth   value   year
  0.130988  19.8414 2009
  0.146459  2.98164 2009
  0.161929  1.70823 2009
  0.177399  1.26972 2009
  0.192869  1.97404 2009
  1.24153   25.1569 2008
  1.28236   46.9919 2008
  1.32216   7.34275 2008
  1.56513   3.25933 2008
  1.61322   2.69906 2008
  1.65984   14.7255 2008
  3.1255    6.39838 2007
```

I need to split total "depth" of each "year" into three equal length and get "mean", "median", "standard deviation" of "value" in that three lengths. I was successful to interpolate values and get three values in that three depth points as below. But I do not want to get one value for one depth point, but get summary for one depth range. For example, I want to get mean, median, standard deviation of length1, length2 and length3 of a year, when I split total depth of a year into three length (length1, length2, and length3)

```
    yr2009<-subset(data, year==2009)
    yr2009<-approx(yr2009$depth, yr2009$value, rule=1,method='linear', xout=seq(min(yr2009$depth), max(yr2009$depth),length.out=3)) # getting data. no need f function
```

I also tried to get three lengths of a year, but it does not work.
        a <- seq(from=min(yr2009$depth), to=max(yr2009$depth), length.out=3)

Thank you very much for your help!!!!!

Comment: What do you want to do with 2007 that has just one observation? You can't really get three groups for that.

Comment: This is a part of my dataset. I actually have more than 10 datapoints for a year. Year in my data is from 2009 to 1998, and this data shown here is a part of summer data only. So I have winter data as well. But if I know how to deal with this dataset, I can apply for all my dataset. Thanks for looking at my post! :)

Comment: There are also cases in the sample dataset where if you split the depth evenly into three sections based on min/max, there are no observations in the middle section. Do you also think that's just a quirk of the data, or do you want to do something special then.

Comment: I need to split annual depth into three sections using min/max depth of a year. Between two years, two depths have a gap, which is because I select only summer data here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one strategy. I took out the 2007 values because it was causing problems, so the sampel data is

```
dd <- structure(list(depth = c(0.130988, 0.146459, 0.161929, 0.177399, 
0.192869, 1.24153, 1.28236, 1.32216, 1.56513, 1.61322, 1.65984
), value = c(19.8414, 2.98164, 1.70823, 1.26972, 1.97404, 25.1569, 
46.9919, 7.34275, 3.25933, 2.69906, 14.7255), year = c(2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L)), .Names = c("depth", "value", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I define some helper functions to use for the even breaking

```
evenbreaks<-function(x, n=3) {
    seq(min(x), max(x), length.out=n+1)
}
evencuts<-function(x, n=3) {
    cut(x, evenbreaks(x, n), include.lowest=T, labels=F)
}
```

Then we split the values for depth up for each year to get a group of 1,2 or 3

```
yeargroup<-with(dd, ave(depth, year, FUN=evencuts))
```

Now we define the stats we want

```
stats<-function(x) {
   c(mean=mean(x), median=median(x), sd=sd(x))
}
```

And use this function to summarize the data

```
aggregate(value~yeargroup+year, dd, stats)
```

This gives

```
  yeargroup year value.mean value.median   value.sd
1         1 2008 26.4971833   25.1569000 19.8585257
2         3 2008  6.8946300    3.2593300  6.7875157
3         1 2009 11.4115200   11.4115200 11.9216506
4         2 2009  1.7082300    1.7082300         NA
5         3 2009  1.6218800    1.6218800  0.4980294
```

Comment: Oh, it is wonderful!!! Thanks a lot for your help!! I learned a lot from you!! :)